# Python 2.7 syntax error

Tags: python, python-2.7, syntax-error, python-2.6

Why is there a syntax error in the below?

```
self.update( { (u,v) : t for (u,v),t in old_items if u in new_vert and v in new_vert } )
                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: What is old_items.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: Can you have a dictionary comprehension with `(u, v)` as the key?

Comment: @Blender: yes, you can. That's a tuple so it's hashable. A list, on the other hand, would raise a TypeError.

Comment: @AdamBernier depends on the `u` and `v` actually (e.g. `(1, [2])` would fail).  But the error would not be `SyntaxError` it would be `TypeError`.

Comment: @OP : does your python support dict comprehensions?  check with `{x:0 for x in range(10)}`

Comment: the old_items will be the initial value, in which we are trying to update the value iteratively.

Answer (score 1):

It's a syntax error because you aren't using Python 2.7.  Double-check the version of your interpreter.  Type "python -V" (capital-V) to see.

Comment: So sorry, I just check with it, it's python 2.6.5. Another question raise in python 2.7 as follows: For: dump=open("table/matrix.pkl",'w'). Problem: IOError:[Errno 2] No such file or directory:'table/matrix.pkl'. The directory should be generated when the code is executing. Please help on this. Thank you very much.

Comment: @user: you get that error because the directory doesn't exist. Try: `if not os.path.exists(the_dir): os.makedirs(the_dir)`, then try opening the file.

Comment: before the dump=open("table/matrix.pkl",'w') , mkdir("table") is added. It should be able to create a directory with this right?